# Getting a wrong answer on ABCPATH on SPOJ for very long time

Tags: java

```
//Here is the code:
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ABCPATH {

    public static int computeLongest(char[][] connect, int i, int j, int[][] dp) {
        if (dp[i][j] != 0) {
            return dp[i][j];
        }
        int max = 1;
        char c = connect[i][j];
        c++;
        int dy[] = {0, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1};
        int dx[] = {-1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, -1, -1};
        for (int k = 0; k < dx.length; k++) {
            int inew = i + dy[k];
            int jnew = j + dx[k];
            if (inew >= 0 && inew < connect.length && jnew >= 0 && jnew < connect[0].length) {
                if (connect[inew][jnew] == c) {

                    return dp[i][j] = Math.max(max, 1 + computeLongest(connect, inew, jnew, dp));
                }
            }
        }
        return max;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int k = 1;
        int p = 1;
        while (k != -1) {
            String in[] = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            if (Integer.parseInt(in[0]) != 0 && Integer.parseInt(in[1]) != 0) {

                int r = Integer.parseInt(in[0]);
                int c = Integer.parseInt(in[1]);
                char[][] connect = new char[r][c];
                for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                    String in2 = sc.nextLine();
                    for (int j = 0; j < in2.length(); j++) {
                        connect[i][j] = in2.charAt(j);


                    }
                }
                int max = 0;
                int dp[][] = new int[r][c];
                for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                        if (connect[i][j] == 'A') {
                            max = Math.max(max, computeLongest(connect, i, j, dp));
                        }
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Case " + p + ": " + max);
                p++;

            } 
            else {
                k = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The link to the problem is :http://www.spoj.com/problems/ABCPATH/, Even on test 1 it give a wrong answer. But the algo I have used is correct as I have verified from some people 
with successful submissions.

Comment: Always give a description of a problem to the question. Url to SPOJ isn't enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample input from SPOJ gives me the correct answer:

Case 1: 4

Can you provide the input that produces incorrect results?

OK, to help you a bit. Consider these tho cases:

```
3 3
ABC
BFG
CDE
0 0


3 3
ABC
BFD
CGE
0 0
```

They should both return the same results but they don't.

Comment: spoj does not provide you test cases

Comment: You have very small problem there ;) Look at dp array - you don't need it in the first place (or am I missing something). Plus, you are finishing your recursion to early - that's why you are only going right (the first case) without checking the second path :] Hope it helps ;)

Comment: thanks, i got that. dp is being used to reduce the time, else i would get a tle

Answer (score -2):

well, there is no problem in the basic logic.

Maybe a little change in formulation of `dp[i][j]` might help.
Instead of computing `dp[i][j]` inside the for-loop try finding maximum length of path i.e max over all 8 possibilities and then  equatin  that with `dp[i][j]`.

snippet from my code in c++ might help:

```
int  dfs(int i,int j)
{

    if(dp[i][j]!=0)
   {

     return dp[i][j];
   }

  int val=1;
for(int k=0;k<8;k++)
{

    int i1=i+x[k];
    int j1=j+y[k];

    if(i1>=0&&i1<h&&j1>=0&&j1<w)
    {
        if((mat[i1][j1]==mat[i][j]+1 )&& visit[i1][j1]==0)
        {

          //path++; //important don't do this in recursive functions with for loops
          visit[i1][j1]=1;

          //return(dp[i][j]=max(path ,dfs(i1,j1,path+1)));//this is causing problem here
          val=max(val ,1+dfs(i1,j1));



        }
    }

}

return(dp[i][j]=val);

}
```